# Why dbpedia result is not consistant

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm executing the below SPARQL query

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?resource WHERE  { 
?resource a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> . 
{?resource rdfs:label 'Paris'@en.} UNION { ?resource rdfs:label 'France'@en.} 
}
```

I'm executing this [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%20%3Fresource%0AWHERE%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fresource%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPlace%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fresource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Paris%22%40en%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fresource%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22France%22%40en%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A). 
Sometimes I am getting required result and sometimes it returns 502 error ( I get the message that website is under maintenance.....) 
Can you please let me know why result is not consistent and how can I avoid this?

Also inconsistent behavior when I execute through java code :

```
       Query query = QueryFactory.create(sb.toString());
        QueryExecution qexec = 
          QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",  query);
```

Comment: Download the DBpedia dataset and setup your own triple store. Then you have full control. And also full costs of maintenance...

Comment: thanks, can you please suggest some links how to do it?

Comment: What? Downloading the data for DBpedia? I think you should find this by using a search engine resp. going to the DBpedia homepage. Regarding triple stores, it depends on which triple store you want to use. And then each triple store has usually a different mechanism for loading the data but that's indeed mentioned in its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experimental [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is [made available as a public service](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#1%20Querying%20DBpedia), but as such it has no Quality-of-Service (QoS) guarantees.

You can set up your own DBpedia mirror in the Amazon AWS cloud, by [spinning up the pre-populated and dynamically updated AMI](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015).  You can also set up a local mirror, by manually loading the [DBpedia datasets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/datasets/dbpedia-datasets) into your own [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) or other triple or quad store instance.

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and the [DBpedia AMI](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), provides and maintains the [public DBpdia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), and employs me.)

Comment: thanks, what is the cost involved in this? Is there any open source available?

Comment: The AMI includes use of the Commercial Edition Virtuoso instance thereon; pricing depends on the AMI machine type you choose. If setting up a local mirror, you can use either Commercial or Open Source; which one you should deploy, depends on which other [features you want to use](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/); if Commercial, pricing varies with scale of use and other chosen options. There are also several links in my answer, above; they all lead to useful details.