# How to Query DBpedia file dumps?

Tags: python, semantic-web, dbpedia

How can I get information about entities from DBpedia data dumps using Python?

Most of post currently on stackoverflow are working with an endpoint and not wuth a data dump file (like https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/querying-dbpedia-from-python) using [SPARQL Endpoint interface to Python](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/)

[One](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/wikipedia_principal_eigenvector.html) of the scikit-learn's implementation of working with it simply iterates through it and puts them in a dictionary

For example, if want to find out about the celebrities born on a certain date just from the properties of [info-box data dumps](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core-i18n/en/infobox-properties_en.nt.bz2).

I tried doing the same using the SPARQL endpoint interface, but obviously it didn't work with the data dump.

Comment: Why do you need to work with data dumps when there's a public SPARQL endpoint available? - There may be reasons why you want to do that and it would be good to understand them [before answering].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would load this data into an RDF store (install one if you don't already have it) and query it using SPARQL.

By doing that you would create a local DBPedia mirror. Considering that DBPedia already provides a SPARQL endpoint is there any reason why you can't just use it?

> This StackOverflow answer mentions the options you have for setting up a local DBPedia mirror: [Why dbpedia result is not consistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118488/why-dbpedia-result-is-not-consistant)

None of this is Python-specific – SPARQL is a standard query language for RDF data.

Alternatively you could iterate through the file looking for the information needed on-the-fly. This way you loose flexibility (the "query" is your code) but can save on memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your input, do you know where one can find more specific endpoint like for a specific dataset like the dump?

Comment: You won't need a more specific endpoint – the standard endpoint (e.g. http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql ) contains data from a number of DBPedia data files, including the infobox dataset you mentioned.